# How to display datetime from MySQL to a web app using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, mysql

I'm having a hard time displaying information from a MySQL database to my web application.

I have this in my db:[image: db].

What I need is to display that date in my web application which looks like:[image: this].

The name place and from field are displayed correctly as you can see but the date is undefined and I ran out of "Google searches" like literally nobody asked this question! I want to mention that when using swagger or postman the item is created as it should be. But when I create it from my web app the request looks like:[image: this]

It's always null! Why?

How should my JS code should look like or what in the name of heavens should I do to make it work here is my js code:

```
window.TrackYourThings = {
API_BASE_URL: "http://localhost:8088/items",

createItem: function () {

    var name = $("#name-field").val();
    var place = $("#place-field").val();
    var fromWho = $("#from-field").val();
    var date = $("#date").val();

    var item = {
        name: name,
        place: place,
        fromWho: fromWho,
        date: date
    };

    $.ajax({
        url: TrackYourThings.API_BASE_URL,
        method: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: JSON.stringify(item)
    }).done(function (response) {
        TrackYourThings.getItems()
    })
},

getItems: function () {
    $.ajax({
        url: TrackYourThings.API_BASE_URL,
        method: "GET",
    }).done(function (response) {
        TrackYourThings.displayItems(response.content);
    })
},

displayItems: function (items) {
    var allItemsHtml = "";

    items.forEach(item => allItemsHtml += TrackYourThings.getItemHtml(item));

    $("#table tbody").html(allItemsHtml);
},

getItemHtml: function (item) {

    return `<tr>
        <td>${item.name}</td>
        <td><label for="type-field"></label>
            <select name="types" id="type-field">
                <option value="Personal">Personal</option>
                <option value="Work">Work</option>
                <option value="Home">Home</option>
                <option value="Important">Important</option>
            </select></td>
        <td>${item.place}</td>
        <td>${item.fromWho}</td>
        <td>${item.date}</td>
        <td><a href="#" class="delete-item fa fa-trash" data-id="${item.id}"></a>
            <a href="#" class="edit-item fa fa-pencil"></a>
        </td>
    </tr>`

},

deleteItem: function (itemId) {
    $.ajax({
        url: TrackYourThings.API_BASE_URL + "?id=" + itemId,
        method: "DELETE",
    }).done(function (response) {
        TrackYourThings.getItems();
    })
},

bindEvents: function () {
    $("#table-form").submit(function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        TrackYourThings.createItem()
    });

    $("#table").delegate(".delete-item", "click", function (event) {
        event.preventDefault();

        var itemId = $(this).data("id");

        TrackYourThings.deleteItem(itemId);
    });
}
```

};

TrackYourThings.getItems();
TrackYourThings.bindEvents();

Comment: In `createItem` can you `console.log(item)`. And in getItems, can you `console.log(response.content)`?

Comment: Sure, I just did that and the console log for createItem indeed shows that is creating an item with the date:
{name: "test", place: "test", fromWho: "test", date: "2021-02-17T13:10"}
date: "2021-02-17T13:10"
fromWho: "test"
name: "test"
place: "test"

But, the getItems shows this:
datetime: null
fromWho: "test"
id: 14
name: "test"
place: "test"
types: null

Comment: Can it be from back-end? The request is still like in the picture from the original post.

Comment: If response.content from getItems has a datetime of null the problem is probably on your backend. Check if your saving it properly and check the query when your fetching the items on the backend.

Comment: Yes, indeed it was from back-end! Thank you so much! One last question if I may, do you know how to correctly show the time in MySQL? I mean now that it's working let's say I put the date as: 13-02-2021 and time as right now: 14:17 but in my DB is 12:17 it's 2 hours ago. It only affects the DB.

Comment: Probably a timezone problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think you've made a mistake in retrieving the `date` data, because null/undefined means there is no data. As far as I can see there's no `date` field in your database, but there's a `datetime` field.

Try changing the following:

```js
var date = $("#date").val();
```

To:

```js
var date = $("#datetime-field").val();
```

Comment: Umm, actually at var date = $("#date").val(); The #date is just the id I've used in HTML it looks like this: <input type="datetime-local" id="date">. But I've tried like your said changing it to #datetime-field but it's still the same.:(